# boto3 describe_fleets api does not fetch all fleet information

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have created few ec2 fleet using boto3 [create_fleet](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_fleet) api. Now i want to see all fleet created in region for that i am trying to use [describe_fleets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_fleets). Here is snippet.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.describe_fleets()
print("result1:",response)
response = client.describe_fleets(FleetIds=['fleet-2342'])
print("result2:",response)
```

output

```
result1: {'Fleets': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {....
result2: {'Fleets': [{'ActivityStatus': 'fulfilled',
```

If i don't pass any fleet ids it give me empty result. but if i pass fleet ids it fetch information.

Why describe_fleets without any argument does not fetch all fleet created in region ?

Comment: What happens if you use the AWS CLI [`describe-fleets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-fleets.html) command? Also, it is worth checking that you are on the latest version of boto3 (`pip install boto3 --upgrade`).

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, same result with aws cli as well, i have upgraded both boto3 as well as aws cli to latest version.

Comment: To reproduce your situation, I created a Spot Fleet via the management console. It did _not_ appear in `aws ec2 describe-fleets`. I then created a fleet via `aws ec2 create-fleet`. It _does_ appear in `aws ec2 describe-fleets`.

Comment: I think ec2 fleet and spot fleet are two different entity. Since boto3 also has different api both of them, [request_spot_fleet](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=spot%20fleet#EC2.Client.request_spot_fleet) is for spot fleet and [create_fleet](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=spot%20fleet#EC2.Client.create_fleet) for ec2 fleet.

Comment: I have also created spot fleet and it seems that describe-spot-fleet-requests api from aws cli works completely fine.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, Thanks for help. I have followed example from https://github.com/awslabs/ec2-spot-labs/tree/master/ec2-fleet and i can see the created fleet in describe-fleets output. I think if i create `instant` type fleet then describe-fleets does not fetch it. I am not sure why